# AWS Lambda RDS restore from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to restore the latest snapshot from production’s DB to staging’s DB (AWS RDS Mysql) and mysql dump that restored DB into EC2 instance.

Comment: A new Amazon RDS instance can be created from a snapshot (see [Restoring from a DB snapshot - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html)). This can be triggered programmatically with [`restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot) -- there is an equivalent available for AWS SDKs in other languages.

Comment: Thanks John , i am using same AWS cli and addes in shell script

Comment: i will share my script ,when it will be done , still iam creating the script ;)